# How do I add an "Add to Favorites" button or link on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarks

I'm building a website using Drupal. On the header of each page I want to have a single image (custom designed by me) which would act as a custom "Add to Favorites" button. Clicking on the image should add the website's URL to the user browser's favorites (bookmarks). This should work for all browsers, IE7+, FF, Opera, Chrome.
I wasn't able to find much information for this online. I suppose that javascript should do the job but I don't have much experience in Javascript :) so I need your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bookmark on click using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828965/bookmark-on-click-using-jquery)

Comment: TL;DR you could try a [Web Extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/bookmark-it) or you could simply create an absolute link with `rel="bookmark" on the page so the user can decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

jQuery Version

```js
$(function() {
  $('#bookmarkme').click(function() {
    if (window.sidebar && window.sidebar.addPanel) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
      window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title, window.location.href, '');
    } else if (window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) { // IE Favorite
      window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
    } else if (window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
      this.title = document.title;
      return true;
    } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
      alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != -1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark This Page</a>
```

Comment: @Whymarrh, added a webkit (Chrome/Safari) action.

Comment: @webmaniacgr see the update. Yes. And please actually +1 then accept.

Comment: I edited the answer because `window.sidebar.addPanel` take the title as the first parameter and the url as the second one.

Comment: @enguerran You are absolutely right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.sidebar - Updated.

Comment: this doesn't work on ie now.. @PHPst's answer does though.. maybe this needs to be updated. thanks!

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work on opera. Only IE popup the bookmark box, Firefox, Chrome and safari(Windows) all alert.

Comment: Firefox's propriety `window.sidebar.addPanel(..)` has been deprecated, and [the function was removed in Firefox 23](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/23#DOM) (see third bullet)

Comment: Yes, It has stopped working in Firefox. Has anyone found another solution?

Comment: Very useful snippet. Especially the Ctrl/Cmd comparison.

Comment: **Update: November 2017** It's such a shame that the appropriate organisations still haven't standardised this yet.  This is still the best/only solution.

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete, any update would be welcome.

Comment: In Firefox 61, it is enough just to have `rel="sidebar" title="Name of bookmark"` to make it work. The JS code lines 3-4 should be updated to this to avoid alert:  `if (window.sidebar) { /* Firefox */ if (window.sidebar.addPanel) window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title, window.location.href, ''); else return true;`

Comment: I found that `href="#"` was causing IE to try to follow a nonexistent link if adding the bookmark was cancelled by the user. Fixed this by removing `href` and adding `style="cursor:pointer"` so users will still realize it is clickable.

Answer (score 23):

This code is the corrected version of iambriansreed's answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#bookmarkme").click(function() {
            // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
            if ('sidebar' in window && 'addPanel' in window.sidebar) { 
                window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
            } else if( /*@cc_on!@*/false) { // IE Favorite
                window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); 
            } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
                alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != - 1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! this works on ie unlike the accepted answer.. (on forced ie9 mode on ie10)

Comment: **UPDATE: this will fail if you have an element with an id=sidebar**, check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747578/uncaught-typeerror-object-htmldivelement-has-no-method-addpanel/17747873?noredirect=1#comment25877287_17747873

Comment: Firefox with an element with id=sidebar. Check the question above.. its fixed though

Comment: Just tried the script but it only popup the bookmark box on IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari(Windows) all alert.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced some problems with rel="sidebar". when I add it in link tag bookmarking will work on FF but stop working in other browser. so I fix that by adding rel="sidebar" dynamic by code:

```
jQuery('.bookmarkMeLink').click(function() {
    if (window.sidebar && window.sidebar.addPanel) { 
        // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title,window.location.href,'');
    }
    else if(window.sidebar && jQuery.browser.mozilla){
        //for other version of FF add rel="sidebar" to link like this:
        //<a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark This Page</a>
        jQuery(this).attr('rel', 'sidebar');
    }
    else if(window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) { 
        // IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); 
    } else if(window.opera && window.print) { 
        // Opera Hotlist
        this.title=document.title;
        return true;
    } else { 
        // webkit - safari/chrome
        alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != - 1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
     window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title,location.href,"");
```

It adds the bookmark but in the sidebar.

Comment: location.href,document.title, - should be in an opposite order

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [@Gert Grenander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024745/cross-browser-bookmark-add-to-favorites-javascript/3024846#3024846) , [@Alaa.Kh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/how-do-i-add-an-add-to-favorites-button-or-link-on-my-website/19162706#19162706) , and [Ross Shanon](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/addtofavorites.html)

Trying to make some order:

it all works - all but the firefox bookmarking function.
for some reason the 'window.sidebar.addPanel' is not a function for the debugger, though it is working fine.

The problem is that it takes its values from the calling `<a ..>` tag: title as the bookmark name and href as the bookmark address.
so this is my code:

javascript:

```
$("#bookmarkme").click(function () {
  var url = 'http://' + location.host; // i'm in a sub-page and bookmarking the home page
  var name = "Snir's Homepage";

  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1){ //chrome
    alert("In order to bookmark go to the homepage and press " 
        + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != -1 ? 
            'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + "+D.")
  } 
  else if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
    //important for firefox to add bookmarks - remember to check out the checkbox on the popup
    $(this).attr('rel', 'sidebar');
    //set the appropriate attributes
    $(this).attr('href', url);
    $(this).attr('title', name);

    //add bookmark:
    //  window.sidebar.addPanel(name, url, '');
    //  window.sidebar.addPanel(url, name, '');
    window.sidebar.addPanel('', '', '');
  } 
  else if (window.external) { // IE Favorite
        window.external.addFavorite(url, name);
  } 
  return;
});
```

html:

```
  <a id="bookmarkme" href="#" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark This Page</a>
```

---

In internet explorer there is a different between 'addFavorite':
`<a href="javascript:window.external.addFavorite('http://tiny.cc/snir','snir-site')">..</a>` 
and 'AddFavorite': `<span onclick="window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);">..</span>`.

example here: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/addtofavorites.html

Important, in chrome we can't add bookmarks using js ([aspnet-i](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=3644865)):
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/452899/How-to-add-bookmark-in-Google-Chrome-Opera-and-Saf