# Bookmark Javascript not jquery for website

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following bookmark Javascript.

```
function bookmark(title, url) {
   if(document.all) { // ie
       window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
   }
   else if(window.sidebar) { // firefox
      window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");
  }
    else if(window.opera && window.print) { // opera
       var elem = document.createElement('a');
       elem.setAttribute('href',url);
       elem.setAttribute('title',title);
       elem.setAttribute('rel','sidebar');
       elem.click(); // this.title=document.title;
    }
}
```

AND HTML

```
<a href="javascript:bookmark('title of the page', 'http://www.domain.com');" class="bookmark" >
```

And the problem is that is working only in Internet Explorer. Is not working in firefox, opera, chrome. Also i heard that firefox have deprecated the function window.sidebar.addPanel, is there any way to fix all of this? PLEASE NO JQUERY.

Comment: Every browser has functionality to add bookmarks integrated in its UI already – so why would you even want to duplicate that?

Comment: @CBroe So i can tell to the user to remind him that he can bookmark the site. And to do it in a easy way, like in one click, with no shortcut keys...

Comment: There are lots of **Related** questions that seem to be on topic. Don't any of them answer your question?

Comment: @Barmar most of them are with Jquery and there were some with Javascript, but did not solved my problem. Tried a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/add-to-favorites-button seems to have non-jQuery methods for most browsers. But they look the same as what you're doing, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Barmar That is JQuery for all answers. And the last answers have window.sidebar.addPanel which had been deprecated from firefox.

Comment: The only jQuery in the answers is in the event binding, not in how it adds the bookmark.

Comment: @Barmar well i am kind of noob, but id it contains Jquery i can't implemented because i don't have and don't want to add the jquery library on my site. It takes too much space and i have my site with 99% A+ on gt metrix, i am kind of a page speed freak.

Comment: You don't need jQuery to copy the parts that set the bookmark. They work the same no matter how you bind the handler.

Comment: @Barmar Could you please help me with a final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to use the answer from [How do I add an "Add to Favorites" button or link on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/add-to-favorites-button?lq=1) without the jQuery event binding.

```
function bookmark(title, href) {
    if (window.sidebar && window.sidebar.addPanel) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(title,href,'');
    } else if(window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) { // IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite(href,title); 
    } else if(window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
        this.title=title;
        return true;
    } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
        alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != - 1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are some problem with the above solution.**

```
   window.sidebar.addPanel("", "","");
```

The above code may not work in all **Mozilla Firefox** versions.
So I wrote the bookmaking code as below. 
*It will work fine in all browsers except webkit - safari/chrome.*

**Add "a" tag as shown below**

```
<a id="BookmarkMe" href="">Bookmark</a>
```

**And used below Jquery**

```
$(function () {
            $('#BookmarkMe').click(function (e) {
                var bTitle = document.title, bUrl = window.location.href;
                if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) { // Mozilla Firefox or Opera
                    if (window.sidebar.addPanel) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        window.sidebar.addPanel(bTitle, bUrl, "");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#BookmarkMe').attr("href", bUrl);
                        $('#BookmarkMe').attr("title", bTitle);
                        $('#BookmarkMe').attr("rel", "sidebar");
                    }
                } else if ($.browser.msie) { // IE Favorite
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.external.AddFavorite(bUrl, bTitle);
                } else { // webkit - safari/chrome
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != -1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
                }
            });
        });
```