# how to bookmark page in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying the below code to bookmark page in Safari. But not working

```
$("#Bookmark").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var bookmarkUrl = this.href;
    var bookmarkTitle = this.title;

    if (window.sidebar) { // For Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(bookmarkTitle, bookmarkUrl, "");
    } else if (window.external || document.all) { // For IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite(bookmarkUrl, bookmarkTitle);
    } else if (window.opera) { // For Opera Browsers
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("href", bookmarkUrl);
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("title", bookmarkTitle);
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("rel", "sidebar");
    } else { // for other browsers which does not support
        alert('Your browser does not support this bookmark action');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the user to add a website to his bookmarks in safari.

The solution would be to inform the user about the shortkey to add to bookmark : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033250/2219239