# Add to bookmark browser data SELECT from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, bookmarks

I have an application build in php that show some data SELECT from a database build in MYSQL. These data are show as link where you can click on and the appaer as document.
Is it possible to add a function with a button star that add me these links (that extract data from a MYSQL table) to my bookmark browser?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/how-do-i-add-an-add-to-favorites-button-or-link-on-my-website

Answer (score 1):

Providing the data is accessible through some unique URL, most simply achieved with `$_GET` variables, then yes. You can even obfuscate the `$_GET` string using mod_rewrite to make more attractive URLs, so instead of `http://domain.com/?document=document_name` you could have `http://domain.com/documents/document_name/` as the URL.

Then it's simply a question of using JS to implement the add bookmark function, which is explained (as @SevStryker pointed out) shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/how-do-i-add-an-add-to-favorites-button-or-link-on-my-website)