# Store TYPO3 fluid request variables (i.e. searchform) for bookmarks

Tags: typo3, fluid, bookmarks, extbase

What's the best practice to be able to store fluid form variables as a bookmark (for simple search filter storing)?

We have a simple extbase&fluid plugin that shows searchfilters and searchresults. The filters are a collection of input and select fields, all created with . Fluid puts in a lot of extra parameters with _referred information and chash's into the request.

Now we want a visitor to be able to bookmark a search result easily. If we use a HTTP GET request, the URL sadly exceeds the URL variable limit because of all the extra parameters; and without them, the fluid plugin won't take on the arguments (unless we disable caching of the whole page?).

Answer (score 0):

The best way (imo) is to generate a clean url that can be stored. In Fluid you can add a link with only the parameters you need and add an onclick event with JS to add this link as a bookmark.

```
<f:link.action action="yourAction" controller="yourController" arguments="{filterArguments}">Add Bookmark</f:link.action>
```

How to add the bookmark function with js(jQuery):
[How do I add an "Add to Favorites" button or link on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033215/how-do-i-add-an-add-to-favorites-button-or-link-on-my-website)

It is also a good practice to configure realurl to produce nice urls for your extension

Comment: Thanks. I see, using realurl will then get rid of those extra parameters, I guess.

Comment: No, using realurl will not get rid of the _referrer and hmac variables, it will only make the link look nicer. Generating the link the way i described will get rid of the extra variables in the url